# Cubic graphs, unfriendly partitions and hamiltonicity

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

We say that a $2$-coloring of a graph $G$ is *unfriendly* if every vertex has at least as many neighbors of the color opposite to his own. Such a coloring always exist and can be obtained by partitioning the graph into two sets that maximize the number of edges between them.

Specifically for a cubic graph $G$ a unfriendly coloring is a partition $(A,B)$  of $V(G)$ so that every vertex in $A$ has at least two neighbors in $B$ and vice versa.

We say that a cubic graph is *imbalanced* if it has a unfriendly partition where the two parts have different sizes.

For example, $K_4$ is *not* imbalanced and so isn't the cube graph $Q_3$.

Out of $1413230$ cubic planar graphs on at most $24$ vertices, there are precisely $2160$ graphs that are not imbalanced and they are all Hamiltonian. Similarly all snarks on up to $32$ vertices are imbalanced.

Hence I wonder

> Is every cubic non-Hamiltonian graph imbalanced?

I would like to understand the notion of imbalanced a little bit better, so any other structural remarks about such graphs are also welcome.

Comment: You probably need to add "planar" or "2-edge-connected" in your question, otherwise the answer is negative. Consider two copies of $K_{3,3}$, remove an edge $uv$ in the first copy, and an edge $xy$ in the second copy. Then add two vertices $w$ and $z$, joined by an edge, such that $w$ is adjacent to $u$ and $v$, and $z$ is adjacent to $x$ and $y$. It is not difficult to show that an unfriendly partition is necessarily a proper 2-coloring, and is therefore balanced.
You should maybe look at this paper related to your question https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03500

Comment: I don't understand where you get your numbers from. Starting from 4 vertices, there are 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 50, 233, 1249, 7595, 49566, 339722 planar cubic graphs as per OEIS https://oeis.org/A000109. How do you get 1.4 million?